# Definition of a matrix inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I thought that the definition of the inner product in a matrix was $\langle X, X\rangle = X^T A X$, but I've seen it used as $\langle X, X\rangle = X^TX$ For example in this thread: [Showing $A-I$ is invertible, when $A$ is a skew-symmetric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110877/showing-a-i-is-invertible-when-a-is-a-skew-symmetric-matrix)

Which one is it?

Comment: In your notation, what is $A$?

Comment: $\langle \mathbf x, \mathbf x\rangle = \mathbf x^T A \mathbf x$ (with positive definite A) is a generalization of $\langle \mathbf x, \mathbf x\rangle = \mathbf x^T \mathbf x$

Comment: An inner product is a binary function on a vector space (i.e. it takes two inputs from the vector space) which outputs a scalar, and which satisfies some other axioms (positive definiteness, linearity, and symmetry).  For example, the "usual" inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the dot product, i.e. $$ \langle x,y\rangle = x\cdot y = x^Ty. $$  However, as Doug M points out, if $A$ is any positive definite matrix, then $$\langle x, y\rangle = x^T A y $$ will also define an inner product.

Comment: Adding onto @XanderHenderson's comment, the vector space optimization book by Luenberger gives an exercise where, for symmetric positive-definite (SPD) matrices $Q$, the expression $(X, Y) = \operatorname{Tr}(X^T Q Y)$ defines an inner product (and in fact, as the exercise gives, a Hilbert space).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is, essentially, "both".  To make sense of that, we first need to get our hands on an *inner product space*, which consists of two pieces:  a vector space $V$, and an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.  These are defined as follows:

> **Definition:**  A *vector space* consists of a set $V$ and a field $\mathbb{F}$, together with two operations $+ : V\times V \to V$ (*vector addition*) and $\cdot : \mathbb{F}\times V \to V$ (*scalar multiplication*) satisfying the axioms
>
> 1. $(V,+)$ is a group (with all that entails).
> 2. Scalar multiplication "plays nice" with the group structure, in the sense that for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ and $u,v\in V$, we have
>
>    - $0_{\mathbb{F}}\cdot v = 0_V$ ($0_\mathbb{F}$ and $0_V$ are the additive identities in $\mathbb{F}$ and $V$, respectively)
>    - $1_{\mathbb{F}}\cdot v = v$ ($1_\mathbb{F}$ is the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb{F}$, and
>    - $\alpha \cdot(u + v) = \alpha\cdot u + \alpha \cdot v$.

If we care about the base field and operations, we might specify a vector space by the tuple $(V, \mathbb{F}, +, \cdot)$.  However, we will typically simply write $V$.  We also typically elide scalar multiplication and write $\alpha v := \alpha \cdot v$.

> **Definition:** Given a real vector space $V$ (i.e. a vector space where $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$), an *inner product* on $V$ is a function $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : V\times V \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the axioms
>
> 1. $\langle v, v \rangle \ge 0$ with equality if and only if $v = 0$,
> 2. $\langle u, v \rangle = \langle v, u \rangle$ for all $u,v\in V$,
> 3. $\langle u+v, w \rangle = \langle u, w\rangle + \langle v, w\rangle$ for all $u,v,w\in V$, and
> 4. $\langle \alpha u, v\rangle = \alpha\langle u,v\rangle$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u,v\in V$.

Inner products generalize the notion of a dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but can be much more general.  As a basic example, the set of square integrable functions
$$L^2(\mathbb{R}) = \left\{ f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \ \middle|\  \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|^2(x)\,\mathrm{d}x < \infty \right\}$$
is a vector space.  The pairing $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle : L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$ \langle f, g \rangle := \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x)\, \mathrm{d}x $$
defines an inner product on that vector space (it is a good exercise to show that this is true).  Note that we can also generalize this idea to vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ without doing too much extra work.

With three two basic definitions in mind, it is now possible to discuss the examples given in the question:

> I thought that the definition of the inner product in a matrix was $\langle X, X\rangle = X^T A X$, but I've seen it used as $\langle X, X\rangle = X^TX$.

First, I don't want to type capital letters over and over again, so I'll use lowercase letters for vectors, e.g. $x, y, z$.

Second, $x \mapsto x^T x$ doesn't define an inner product (though it can define a norm under the right conditions), since it takes only one input.  An inner product must take two inputs.  Thus I am going to assume that you wish to define an inner product by
$$ \langle x, y \rangle = x^Ty. $$

Third, I think that if we are going to discuss inner products, then we must assume that $x$ is not a matrix, but a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Otherwise, if $x$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, then $x^T x$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, which is not a scalar.  In this case, the map $(x,y) \mapsto x^Ty$ cannot possibly define an inner product.  Thus let us now assume that our vectors are elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Under these three assumptions, then we can define the "usual" inner product (or *dot product*) on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$ \langle x, y \rangle = x\cdot y = x^Ty. $$
It is not too hard to check that this is actually an inner product.  However, this is not the *only* inner product that can be defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Indeed, if $A$ is any symmetric, positive definite $n\times n$ matrix with real entries, then the pairing
$$ \langle x, y \rangle := x^T A y $$
will define an inner product.  This is slightly more difficult to check, but still quite doable—there is slightly more bookkeeping to be done to keep track of matrix entires, and you have to keep in mind the meaning of a "symmetric, positive definite" matrix (positive definiteness means that $x^T A x \ge 0$ with equality iff $x = 0$, and symmetry ensures that $x^T A y = y^T A x$).

The moral of the story is that both
$$ (x,y) \mapsto x^Ty
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
(x,y) \mapsto x^T A y $$
can define inner products on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Indeed, Sean Roberson gives a third nice example of an inner product on this space.  There is no *single* inner product here—there are myriad inner products that can be defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the particular choice depending on the intended application.